# Display in json api table view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking

You want to appear in the json api table view. But I do not know how.

```
import Foundation

class MovieAPI {

    enum Endpoint {
        static let base = "http://connect-boxoffice.run.goorm.io"

        case listOrder(Int)

        var url: URL {
            return URL(string: self.stringValue)!
        }

        var stringValue: String {
            switch self {

            case .listOrder(let orderType): return Endpoint.base + "/movies?order_type=\(orderType)"
            }
        }
    }

    class func requestListOrder(listOrder: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (ListOrder?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let listOrderEndpoint = MovieAPI.Endpoint.listOrder(listOrder).url
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: listOrderEndpoint) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let movieData = try! decoder.decode(ListOrder.self, from: data)
            print(movieData)
            completionHandler(movieData, nil)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

When I see print (movieData), the movie list is output, and I want to display the list in the table view.

Comment: What have you tried? have you searched google for such easy solutioned question?

Answer (score 0):

Call the requestListOrder method it would give you completion with listorder, reload tableview after the completion is sucessfull.
You just have to pass the listorder data array to tableview datasource method and reloading the tableview

```
extension MyViewController:UITableViewDataSource{


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listorder.data.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! YourCell
    cell.yourdata = listorder.data[indexpath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the class function requestListOrder function it would give you completion with movie list and assign it to a variable. Reload tableview after the value is set to the variable by its computed property i.e. didSet.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var movieList = [Movie]() {
    didSet {
          tableView.reloadData()
       }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        MovieAPI.requestListOrder(listOrder: 1) { (movieList, error) in
           if let error = error {
               //handle your error here
               return //this restricts your code below to execute
           }
        self.movieList = movieList.data
      }
   }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.movieList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! YourCell
    cell.yourdata = movieList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

}
```